# Qual a utilidade de usar chaves estrangeiras?

Tags: sql, modelo-relacional, chave-estrangeira

Andei aprendendo sobre chaves estrangeiras e estou com dificuldade de entender qual a utilidade das mesmas. O seu intuito seria "dividir uma tabela em várias tabelas, deixando seus dados sempre atômicos", mas eu simplesmente poderia programar um sistema com segurança para adicionar um valor na coluna de uma segunda tabela com o id da primeira tabela, e ter a mesma segurança ao fazer consultas, etc.

Vamos a um exemplo, onde tenho duas tabelas `users` (id, username, email, password) e `hobbies`(id, hobbie, iduser). Nesse caso a coluna `iduser` seria FK de `id` da tabela `users`, qual seria a real utilidade da chave estrangeira?

No meu entendimento seria dar segurança e integridade aos dados, mas aconteceu comigo de na tabela `users` ter 4 registros, com o último `id` sendo igual a 4 e mesmo assim eu pude inserir um dado na tabela `hobbies` com a coluna `iduser` igual a 5, como isso pode acontecer sendo que não tenho um `id` 5 de usuário?

Outra decepção foi saber que o `crud` não muda, apenas vou ter o `id` da primeira tabela em `SESSION` e usar o `crud` normalmente, aplicando esse valor na coluna `iduser` quando for inserir, e no `where` quando for deletar, consultar ou alterar.

Eu não entendi o conceito de FK, não estou sabendo usar ou é inútil mesmo? Poderiam me dar uma luz? Passei o dia procurando entender sobre isso, entendi, mas na aplicação não vejo nada de mais.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Além de *ajudar a descrever o relacionamento nos modelos*, as chaves estrangeiras são usados principalmente pra manter a integridade dos dados, ou seja imagine que você tem duas tabelas ligadas por uma chave estrangeira e tem dados na tabela `B` ligados a uma especifica linha na tabela `A`, então você, se você tentar deletar esta linha especifica o banco vai lhe impedir e vai enviar um erro.

Antes da chave estrangeira nós tínhamos que controlar e fazer este tipo de prevenção na camada da aplicação ou com "triggers", era um trabalho muito difícil e nem sempre era eficiente.

Vou citar alguns tipos de relações:

### one-to-many, 1 para muitos (`1:n`):

Se na tabela `A` tenho uma linha com a id 3 e na tabela `B` tenho duas linhas ligadas a id 3 e eu tentar deletar esta linha da tabela `A` vai ocorrer um erro.

> O 1 para N, um-para-muitos ou 1:N (em inglês: one-to-many) para se referir a um dos tipos de relacionamentos que se podem estabelecer entre os campos de duas tabelas: cada tupla de uma tabela pode-se relacionar com N tuplas da outra tabela. Porém, cada tupla da segunda tabela só se relaciona com uma única tupla da primeira.
>
> <sub>https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_para_N</sub>

### many-to-many, muitos para muitos (`n:m`)

Se na tabela `A` temos duas ids 35 (joão) e 36 (maria) e na tabela `B` temos os seguintes valores:

| id | nome |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | carro |
| 2 | casa |
| 3 | terreno |
| 4 | kitnet |

Então teremos um terceira tabela que fará a interação entre A e B, podemos chama-la de `A_tem_B` que em um exemplo seria:

| id_A | id_B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 35 |
| 1 | 36 |
| 2 | 35 |
| 3 | 36 |
| 4 | 36 |

O que basicamente a tabela `A_tem_B` está dizendo é:

- João (id 35) tem carro
- Maria (id 36) tem carro
- João tem casa
- Maria tem terreno
- Maria tem kitnet

Se eu tentar deletar `kitnet` (id 4), irá ocorrer um erro, porque ele está vinculado a Maria.

Se eu tentar deletar `carro` (id 1), irá ocorrer um erro, porque Maria e João estão vinculados ao carro.

> No modelo relacional de bases de dados, é usada qualquer uma das expressões N para N, muitos-para-muitos (many-to-many), ou N:N (as vezes também expressa como N:M), para referir um dos tipos de relacionamentos que se podem estabelecer entre os campos de duas tabelas: para cada valor do campo de uma tabela, pode haver N valores no campo da outra tabela e vice-versa.
>
> Em bancos de dados relacionais, esta relação consuma-se através de uma tabela de ligação que faz a correspondência de ambos os lados com relacionamento 1 para N para cada lado. A chave primária surge de forma natural, e é composta pela junção das chaves primárias das tabelas interligadas.
>
> <sub>https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N_para_N</sub>

Mesmo sem chave estrangeira podemos ter um relacionamento entre diferentes tabelas, mas o difícil é manter a integridade, mesmo que usando *triggers* pra tal serviço como citei anteriormente.

### Problema da questão

Se você está conseguindo inserir na tabela hobbies é porque há algo errado em como você modelou, não é um problema com o FK e sim a maneira que você fez, veja um exemplo que funciona:

[image: tabela]

O exemplo é em mysql e innoDB e é um exemplo de muitos para muitos, ou seja dois usuários podem ter o mesmo hobby (não sei qual banco está usando), sql:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios` (
  `idusuarios` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idusuarios`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hobbies` (
  `idhobbies` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hobbie` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idhobbies`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios_has_hobbies` (
  `usuarios_idusuarios` INT NOT NULL,
  `hobbies_idhobbies` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`usuarios_idusuarios`, `hobbies_idhobbies`) ,
  INDEX `fk_usuarios_has_hobbies_hobbies1_idx` (`hobbies_idhobbies` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_usuarios_has_hobbies_usuarios_idx` (`usuarios_idusuarios` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_usuarios_has_hobbies_usuarios`
    FOREIGN KEY (`usuarios_idusuarios`)
    REFERENCES `usuarios` (`idusuarios`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_usuarios_has_hobbies_hobbies1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`hobbies_idhobbies`)
    REFERENCES `hobbies` (`idhobbies`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Então insira um usuário e um hobby, em seguida pegue o `id` do hooby e tente adicionar com um id de usuário que não existe, irá dar este erro:

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint
> fails (`foo`.`usuarios_has_hobbies`, CONSTRAINT
> `fk_usuarios_has_hobbies_hobbies1` FOREIGN KEY (`hobbies_idhobbies`)
> REFERENCES `hobbies` (`idhobbies`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO
> ACTION)

No entanto pela sua explicação se o exemplo dos *hobbies* é hipotético, então talvez sua necessidade não seja `n:m`, pode ser que seja `1:n`, sendo assim o exemplo ficaria assim:

[image: tabela 1:n]

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuarios` (
  `idusuarios` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idusuarios`) )
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hobbies` (
  `idhobbies` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hobbie` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `usuarios_idusuarios` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idhobbies`) ,
  INDEX `fk_hobbies_usuarios_idx` (`usuarios_idusuarios` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_hobbies_usuarios`
    FOREIGN KEY (`usuarios_idusuarios`)
    REFERENCES `usuarios` (`idusuarios`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Neste caso criei um usuário:

```
INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`idusuarios`, `nome`) VALUES ('João'); #id 1
```

Então tente criar um hobby pra ele, assim:

```
INSERT INTO `hobbies` (`hobbie` , `usuarios_idusuarios` ) VALUES ('basquete',  1); #id: 1
```

Depois tente criar um hooby pra um usuário que não existe:

```
INSERT INTO `hobbies` (`hobbie` , `usuarios_idusuarios` ) VALUES ('natação',  1900);
```

Deve ocorrer este erro pois o id 1900 não existe na tabela `usuarios`:

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`foo2`.`hobbies`, CONSTRAINT `fk_hobbies_usuarios` FOREIGN KEY (`usuarios_idusuarios`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`idusuarios`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION)

Fiz os testes aqui (localmente) e funcionou, ocorrendo os erros citados quando devido.

### Software pra modelar em Mysql

Um software para facilitar a modelagem é o *MySQL Workbench* (se usa MySQL) que suporta Windows, Linux e macOS http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Comment: Valeu muito brother! Eu tinha lido sobre essas formas `1:1` `1:N` e `N:N, mas so com sua resposta entendi realmente como cada um funciona. Acho que tem um pequeno erro na resposta, no seu segundo `insert` o `id` não seria 1 né, seria um `id` inexistente na tabela A, como 100? Tenho esse software no meu PC, nunca mexi nele rs sempre usei HeidiSQL e PhPMyAdmin, valeu pela dica!

Comment: @LeonardoVIlarinho O HeidiSQL e PhPMyAdmin são pra gerenciar o banco, pra modelar é o WorkBench, são tarefas diferentes ;) - Aqui você se refere: `INSERT INTO hobbies (hobbie , usuarios_idusuarios) VALUES ('basquete', 1); #id: 1`? Seria 1 sim, pois a tabela é autoincrement e em hobbies não haviam dados ainda. Por favor testes ambos exemplos ;) - Ps.: Adicionei 3 videos aulas do workbench, não assisti, mas parecem ser uteis pra ti.

Comment: Sim, eles são mais para gerenciamento, eu nunca usei nenhum para modelar. Me refiro a linha `INSERT INTO hobbies (hobbie , usuarios_idusuarios ) VALUES ('natação',  1);` (terceiro `insert`, pois no telefone é péssimo ler rs), nela o valor de `usuarios_idusuarios` deveria ser 2 ou maior, para dar o erro. E no primeiro `insert` não precisaria ter especificada a coluna  `idusuarios` já que ela é `auto increment`. Obrigado, os exemplos fizeram eu entender!

Comment: @LeonardoVIlarinho kkkk bem notado, era 1900 o valor, não sei porque sumi com parte do trecho rs

Comment: eu ia fazer uma pergunta que acho que você pode me ajudar Guilherme. Eu posso manter um sistema sem chaves estrangeiras nas tabelas?

Comment: @DiChrist sim é possivel, mas o problema é que a lógica de ligação entre diferentes tabelas terá que ser toda na aplicação (por exemplo classes PHP) e será muito trabalhoso criar algo sem bugs, fora que você não terá um diagrama (workbench tem um) pra saber o que liga com o que, será totalmente orientado a aplicação... Existem frameworks que fazem isto como Laravel é possivel relacionar por aplicação, só que tem dois problemas (dificuldades), dependendo do tipo de banco não conseguirá fazer rollback, a não ser que o framework escolhido o simule e terá que aprender o framework :/

Comment: excelente Guilherme, era isso o que eu precisava saber. Vlw!

Answer (score 10):

## TL;DR

Chaves estrangeiras tem tudo a ver com manter a consistência dos dados.

## Restrições

Definir uma chave estrangeira cria uma ligação entre um registro da tabela de origem com um registro da tabela de destino.

Em geral, se um campo é uma chave estrangeira, cada registro contém naquele campo um identificador válido que referencia um registro existente na outra tabela.

Isso significa que o banco de dados restringe os valores que podem ser colocados naquele campo, verificando se o registro correspondente realmente existe.

Ele também restringe a remoção de registros da tabela referenciada, evitando que você consiga remover registros que sejam referenciados por alguma chave estrangeira.

## Relaxamento das restrições

Alguns bancos de dados possuem mecanismos para desativar as restrições, criando o risco de uma alteração deixar registros órfãos, isto é, que referenciam outros registros não mais existentes.

Outro mecanismos que alguns bancos de dados permitem é remover registros em cascata, isto é, ao deletar um registro referenciado por alguma chave estrangeira, o registro que possui a chave estrangeira também é removido.

Use tais recursos com cuidado, somente se precisar muito.

## Vantagem de usar chaves estrangeiras

A principal vantagem é evitar inconsistências. É ingênuo pensar que *o sistema vai garantir que os registros estejam em ordem* por vários motivos que ninguém consegue antecipar:

- Script com erros executado diretamente na base
- Falta de controle transacional numa operação em várias tabelas
- Falha ao gerenciar leitura ou escrita concorrentes
- Erros no SQL do sistema
- Outros sistemas usando o mesmo banco de dados
- Aquela pessoa que esquece de colocar `WHERE` em `UPDATES` e `DELETES`

A chave estrangeira vai evitar que registros com dependências sejam excluídos sem querer..

## Efeitos colaterais

As restrições causadas pela definição de uma chave estrangeira as vezes irritam os desenvolvedores, principalmente quando eles não entendem o modelo de dados ou quando eles ainda tem pouco conhecimentos sobre banco de dados.

Por exemplo, criar um script para alterar a estrutura da tabela referenciada pode ser uma dor de cabeça, principalmente se a chave primária for modificada ou o tipo do campo mudar.

Também é mais trabalhoso criar dados de exemplo, testes e funcionalidades para remoção de dados.

Enfim, é mais um caso onde a segurança gera um pouco mais de trabalho.

Comment: Depois que passei a entender os relacionamentos na verdade passei a ter muito menos dor de cabeça, com a camada da aplicação, hoje quase não vivo sem, os efeitos colaterais nada mais são a integridade do banco contra a inexperiência de quem usa rs. +1