# SQL SERVER - RELACIONAMENTO 1:N

Tags: sql-server, relacionamento

Tenho duas tabelas: *livros* e *editoras*.

O relacionamento delas foi definido da seguinte maneira, um livro pode ter uma editora e uma editora pode estar em vários livros, ou seja, 1:N.

Aprendi que a chave estrangeira (FK) deve estar na tabela N, no caso, na tabela livros.

Porém, fiz um teste e a coloquei na tabela 1 (editoras). Se essa chave é usada apenas para estabelecer uma relação entre as tabelas, de forma que seja possível fazer uma busca de dados relacionados entre elas, qual é o problema colocar a FK na tabela editoras?

Segue abaixo meu teste:

```
CREATE TABLE Editoas(
    IdEditora INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    FkLivro INT,
    NomeEditora VARCHAR(500),
    EmailEditora VARCHAR(500),
    FOREIGN KEY(FkLivro) REFERENCES Livros(IdLivro)
    );

SELECT * FROM Livros AS L, Editoras AS E
    WHERE L.IdLivro = E.FkLivro;
```

Trouxe os dados relacionados entre as duas tabelas sem problemas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Então qual é o problema em colocar a FK na tabela de 1? Colocar na N seria somente por uma questão de normas, não interfere no resultado das buscas?

Comment: Dessa forma você teria que ter "n" registros de editoras para "n" registros de livros, ou seja, cada livro que você tiver, você — obrigatoriamente — terá que ter um registro de uma editora para ele. Dessa forma você terá muitos dados duplicados e vai afetar a performance etc. Porém, deixar esse campo na tabela "livro", você só precisará ter um registro na tabela "editora" que ele servirá para vários livros.

Comment: Na verdade o que questiono é se essa regra de colocar a FK na tabela N é só por uma questão de normas, alguma regra/ padrão definida pelos analistas/ programadores.

Comment: Tentarei elaborar uma resposta detalhada, mas de cara te digo, *não* as chaves não servem só para seguir normas. Além de deixarem claro como é  o relacionamento da tabelas para quem for dar manutenção futuramente, elas também servem para impedir que ações indevidas sejam executadas, garantindo a integridade dos dados.

Comment: Por exemplo, você poderia me citar um exemplo de relação de 1:N?

Comment: Realmente eu não peguei um bom exemplo de relação 1:N. Já que se for raciocinar bem, posso cadastrar a editora sem informar um livro, já nos livros preciso informar a editora. Se a FK estiver na tabela editora, preciso obrigatoriamente informar o livro.

Comment: Desculpe a demora, tentei pensar em bom exemplo para sanar sua dúvida.  xD

Comment: Que isso, você foi rápido no gatilho!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para responder sua pergunta de forma mais didática, pegarei um exemplo mais simples de relacionamento **1:N**.

Imagine que você foi a uma lavanderia(loja) para lavar suas camisetas e na hora de deixá-las você preencheu um cadastro com seus dados pessoais e quais eram suas camisetas.

Esses dados foram armazenados da seguinte forma:

**Tabela Pessoa:**

```
IdPessoa | Nome
1        | HeyJoe
2        | Caique
```

**Tabela Camiseta:**

```
IdCamiseta | Descricao | IdPessoa
1          | Azul      | 1
2          | Amarela   | 1
3          | Preta     | 2
```

No Exemplo acima fica claro que as camisetas azul e amarela pertencem a pessoa de `IdPessoa = 1`, ou seja, pertencem ao `HeyJoe`.

Sabemos que as camisetas devem obrigatóriamente ter um "dono", uma pessoa.

Imagina que alguém vai lá e apaga do banco de dados o registro da pessoa de `IdPessoa=1`, o que vai acontecer com as camisetas azul e amarela, ficarão na loja para sempre? Não.

Não, podemos pertimir que os registros das pessoas que possuem camisetas lavando sejam apagados, para garantir a integridade da informação. Para isso devemos utilizar o as chaves estrangeiras que acusarão um erro quando tentarmos deletar uma pessoa que possuir camisetas.

Veja em código:

```
CREATE TABLE Pessoa(
    IdPessoa INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Nome VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE Camiseta(
    IdCamiseta INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    Descricao VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    IdPessoa INT NOT NULL 
    CONSTRAINT FK_Camiseta_Pessoa FOREIGN  KEY(IdPessoa) REFERENCES Pessoa(IdPessoa)
)

INSERT INTO Pessoa VALUES ('HeyJoe')
INSERT INTO Pessoa VALUES ('Caique') 


INSERT INTO Camiseta VALUES ('Azul', 1)
INSERT INTO Camiseta VALUES ('Amarela', 1)
INSERT INTO Camiseta VALUES ('Preta', 2)

SELECT * FROM Pessoa, Camiseta WHERE Pessoa.IdPessoa = Camiseta.IdPessoa
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E o que aconteceria se eu tenta-se deletar uma pessoa após fazer o relacionamento com a `FK`:

```
DELETE Pessoa WHERE IDPessoa = 1
```

A operação acima seria cancelada e seguinte erro seria exibido:

> The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint
>   "FK_Camiseta_Pessoa". The conflict occurred in database "Negociacao",
>   table "dbo.Camiseta", column 'IdPessoa'. The statement has been
>   terminated.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

É possível realizar consultas relacionando tabelas que não possuem suas chaves definidas, mas não é por isso que devemos faze-las.

As normas existem por um motivo e o principal motivo da utilização das `FK` é a garantir a integridade dos dados, segue uma outra [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106084/qual-a-utilidade-de-usar-chaves-estrangeiras) que pode te auxiliar.

Comment: Bom, pelo que estou vendo não é uma norma, é simplesmente seguir uma lógica.

Comment: Quando você diz "integridade dos dados" seria o que exatamente? Seria manter a informação sem defeito? Por exemplo, neste caso, se eu deletasse a pessoa e mantivesse suas camisetas, seria um defeito na informação, e isso é perda de integridade dos dados. Estou correto?

Comment: Exatamente a camiseta teria o `IDPessoa=1 ` mas essa pessoa não existiria, esse controle de integridade não é só para exclusões, serve também por exemplo para impedir que eu adicionei um camiseta de `IdPessoa=3` onde essa pessoa também não existiria. Na minha resposta vinculei um link que tem mais detalhes.

Comment: Ao final da fk, para evitar esses erros de integridade de dados pode adicionar ON DELETE CASCADE, RESTRICT, SET NULL, NO ACTION e outros afins