# Como pegar informações que estão em 2 tabelas mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Tabela 01: `$file`

Tabela 02: `$users`

Quero fazer assim, quando um user for level ID = 30 exiba uma msg

EXEMPLO, Arquivo 01 (`$file->userid = 20` ou seja, esse id do user esta na tabela 02, `$users->id`)

---

**TABELA $FILE**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

**TABELA $USERS**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

> Ou seja.. Seria assim: `$file->userId$users->id->levelId` ??

```html
if (QUANDO ESSE ARQUIVO FOR DE UM USER LEVEL 30) {
 echo "teste";
}
```

Comment: A coluna `userid` é uma chave estrangeira? Você conhece a cláusula `join`?

Comment: Não tenho a minima ideia de que está falando, so sei que quando quero pegar uma informação da tabela, eu coloco $file->filename por exemplo.

Comment: Só porque eu sou um cara legal: [Qual a utilidade de usar chaves estrangeiras?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106084/5878) e [Qual é a diferença entre INNER JOIN e OUTER JOIN?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/6441/5878)

Comment: Pode me informar como faço aqui em php? por que não entendi como fazer..

Comment: Desculpe-me, mas julgo que 1 minuto (2 no máximo) são insuficientes para você absorver o conteúdo das 3 perguntas que citei e verificar que não entendeu. Aliás, PHP, neste problema, é irrelevante, já que a questão é SQL.

Comment: no mspaint, selecione a opção "preenchimento" em seguida "cor sólida", Agora você pode fazer um retângulo tampando o hash das senhas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a cláusula `JOIN` do SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM users as u
INNER JOIN file as f ON u.id = f.userId
WHERE u.level_id = 30
```

Explicando, linha:

1. Seleciona tudo a partir da tabela `users`
2. Junta com a tabela `file` onde os ids de cada tabela forem iguais
3. Adiciona uma condição para que retorne apenas os que forem com o nível igual a 30