# O que uma chave estrangeira realmente faz no banco de dados?

Tags: mysql, chave-estrangeira

A chave estrangeira no MySQL faz alguma ação no banco, ou só serve para eu "ver" quais campos estão relacionados há uma tabela auxiliar?

Como faço uma chave estrangeira no MySQL?

Comment: Seja bem vindo Samuel, acredito que você esteja fazendo confusão no conceito de chave estrangeira, 'só serve' ?  Leia está  pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/106084/qual-a-utilidade-de-usar-chaves-estrangeiras/106087

Comment: Pra responder à sua segunda pergunta, especifique qual banco de dados você usa (SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL...)

Comment: MySQL. @ViniciusBrasil

Answer (score 3):

Chave estrangeira (foreign key) é o campo que estabelece o relacionamento entre duas tabelas. Assim, uma coluna corresponde à mesma coluna que é a chave primária de outra tabela. A função do  relacionamento entre tabelas através das chaves estrangeiras é manter a integridade referencial dos dados.

Fonte: [Breve Conceito de Foreing key](https://www.devmedia.com.br/breve-conceito-de-foreing-key/17426)

No MySQL você pode criar a chave estrangeira quando criar a tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders (
    OrderID int NOT NULL,
    OrderNumber int NOT NULL,
    PersonID int,
    PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
    FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonREF)
);
```

Ou após a criação da tabela:

```
ALTER TABLE Orders
ADD FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons(PersonREF);
```

Onde "Order" é a tabela da chave estrangeira e "PersonID" é o campo que buscará os dados do campo de referência "PersonREF" da tabela "Persons".