# No Diagrama de Entidade e Relacionamento coloca-se chave estrangeira?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, der

Perguntei no chatgpt e o robo diz que sim, e que precisa colocar uma seta pontilhada entre as entidades. Porém eu pesquisei no google para procurar exemplos e não consegui achar um Diagrama que tenha essa seta pontilhada, enfim, eu queria saber se no Diagrama de Entidade e Relacionamento usa-se chave estrangeira? ou apenas a chave primaria é colocada?

Comment: Veja se ajuda https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106084/137387

Comment: está falando da tabela relacional, eu queria saber do DER

Answer (score -1):

No modelo conceitual de banco de dados, usa-se o losango para representar um relacionamento entre tabelas, sem a necessidade de adicionar o atributo chave estrangeira na entidade. Enquanto que no modelo lógico, a chave estrangeira deve estar presente na tabela e as tabelas devem estar conectadas por uma linha tracejada.

Vamos exemplificar isso com um modelo imaginário de banco de dados. Vamos pensar que temos 2 tabelas: motorista e veiculo. Onde um motorista pode possuir muitos veículos mas um veículo só pode pertencer a um único motorista.

[image: Modelo conceitual]

Podemos ver que no modelo conceitual não se deve representar a chave estrangeira como atributo, tendo em vista que o losango já realiza o papel de representar o relacionamento entre as tabelas, portanto, fica implícito a existência de um atributo chave estrangeira.

[image: Modelo lógico]

Agora no modelo lógico podemos observar que é necessário representar o atributo chave estrangeira na tabela, além de conecta-las com a linha tracejada.